# Commerce template question

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

I have just completed a fresh install of Craft CMS Pro and the Commerce plugin on my local host.  To view the website I go to localhost:8888 and I see the generic home page that says "Welcome to Localhost. Recent News - We just installed Craft" etc...   My question is, how do I view the page that my sample Commerce template is on that I dropped into the templates folder?  In my templates folder it is `/templates/shop`.  I also still have `/templates/news/` in there that came with the Craft Pro in the `templates` folder as well. Maybe I'm confused but I thought my homepage would be overwritten with some sort of shopping website template, or do I need to go to localhost:8888/xxxxx?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the example templates are designed to be used inside a subdirectory like `/shop`. This does not stop you from putting the example templates anywhere else (like the root template directory), but links inside the example template referencing `/shop` would need to be updated.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. I found the url to my front end sample template, which is localhost:8888/shop/ although the css is broken when I arrive there. It has the page content there but not styles, it is all tucked up in the top left corner, no buttons surrounding the link 'products' etc.  Any ideas on why this could be?